# html_entity_decode equivalent in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, function, escaping

I have HTML escaped string printing in view. But how to decode it to plain text? Have been looking for this for hours. Does Zend Framework have something reverse of `$this->escape()` that can be used in view files? An unescape function in Zend Framework?

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `Zend_View::escape()` uses `htmlspecialchars()` at its heart, you could always just use [htmlspecialchars_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)

Comment: Thanks Phil, I winder if Zend has a way to do this?

Comment: @pMan I'd say the only reason for Zend creating the `escape` view method (other than the fact it's shorter to write) would be to automatically incorporate the `$charset` parameter as set on the view. As `htmlspecialchars_decode` has no such parameter, it's simply not required to create a wrapper.