# Preventing JavaScript inline url injection

Tags: javascript, php, zend-framework, xss

For a field where user inputs their personal website url which is then displayed on their public profile, how can js injection be prevented at the server side.

For example for input value -> 'javascript:/**/alert(document.domain)'

```
if (!preg_match('/^https?:\/\/.*$/D', $value)) {
        $value = 'http://' . $value;
    }
    if(filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) == FALSE){
        return false;
    }
    try {
        $uri = Zend_Uri_Http::fromString($value);
    }
    catch (Zend_Uri_Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
    return $uri->valid();
```

then this would be displayed as :

```
$escapedWebsite = htmlspecialchars($url, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
'<a href="'. $escapedWebsite .'" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">' . $escapedWebsite . '</a>';
```

The page renders as :

```
<a href="javascript:/**/alert(document.domain)" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">javascript:/**/alert(document.domain)</a>
```

Comment: You can't prevent client-side injection into your page using server-side code.

Comment: Are you looking for [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254654/html-entity-decode-equivalent-in-zend-framework)? You want to escape any (possible) html the user is inputting, right?

Comment: You can prevent client-side injection using CSP: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/

Comment: Why don't you just use a regular expression like `/^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/|\/)/`?

Answer (score 0):

Perosnally, I'm fond of using [`parse_url`](https://www.php.net/parse_url) to validate URIs:

```
$incomingUrl = $_POST['website'];
$parsedUrl = parse_url($incomingUrl);

if (parsedUrl !== false) { /* valid! */ }
```

of course you could also use [`filter_input`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php):

```
validate_input(INPUT_POST, 'website', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)
```